# Wordpress - image.php - if no image redirect to home

Tags: wordpress

I use a script for my `image.php`.

The url with an image looks like this:

```
/image.php?title=Alyssa Milano Unicef&description=Alyssa Milano Unicef&url=uploads/2009/12/alyssa_milano_unicef_05.jpg
```

But if someone types directly `www.site.com/image.php` it shows a blank site. A redirection would be nice to the `404 page` or startpage.

I know it must be something like `if else`. If image - then show the page, if there is no picture - go to **404** or the startpage.

Comment: @elmas: You can leave comments (like this one) on your own questions and answers, and on answers to your own questions.  When you gain enough reputation (50) you'll be able to leave comments on any question or answer on the site.  See the FAQ for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

It should be a 403 instead of 404. Try:

```
//if no image
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
header('Location: http://www.site.com/imagebrowser.php');
```

You could also set up imagebrowser under image.php